# Create expandable child row with Material UI Grid in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material UI Grid component for my Grids in a React application which are rendered based on data coming back from an external API. I have a requirement to add a column that allows rows to be expanded to render additional child content beneath each row, as you can do using DataTables here https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Essentially I want to be able to create a nested row and render a component into it dynamically per row.

I dont have any example code of what I have tried as I cannot find anything obvious online or in the Material UI documentation to really get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are talking about `Grid` component but this component is mainly used to create layouts instead (https://mui.com/components/grid/#main-content).

What you are searching for is the following:

https://mui.com/components/tables/#collapsible-table

A table with expandable rows.

Comment: My bad. I am of course using the Grid component for layouts. Its actually the DataGrid component I'm using and need to add the collapsible row too. Regardless, this answer still holds as the DataGrid doesn't support it either, so will have a look at the Collapsable table